# SonarQube, no data for depth inheritance tree and other metrics

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, no-data

Hi this is my first post on legendary Stackoverflow!

I am currently trying to find a platform in order to create an inheritance plugin (in order to calculate metrics) for my thesis and I am trying SonarQube for this purpose. So far, I am learning the basics. The problem is that although everything goes fine, I have a problem when it's time to add a "custom measures" widget. As you can see, the widget shows the message "no data" on configure widget menu, when I add measures like Number of Children, Depth in Tree.

[image]

I have installed SonarQube 3.7 for Windows 7 64bit and SonarQube Runner version 2.3. I have also installed SonarQube on eclipse. My .properties file is this :

[image]

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computing of LCOM4 and RFC metrics is based on byte-code, so if you want to have them, you need to:

- compile your code
- add the "sonar.binaries" property in your file (it should point to the folder where the code was compiled, e.g. "target/classes" or "bin")

As for the 2 other metrics, they are not fed by SonarQube. So we'll eventually remove them (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4643).